# memcpy() by reference and no copy?

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

## Context

Studying memcpy.
yes it works but it would be nice if we could just keep a reference to the subpart of the array we are interested in with no copy at all.

```
char a[] = "hello";
char b[20];
memcpy(b,a,strlen(a)-1)
```

## Question

Could we do the same with no copy at all, just pointer arithmetic ?

```
printf("my array is %s\n",a..a+2)
```

for example ?

The point is not only printf but any reference at any place in the code by a pointer for the beginning and the end. a..a+2 (think socket, function arguments..)

To me copying seems a bit weird for a slice since it should be a reference to the parent array.

Comment: If you don't want to copy then don't use `memcpy` and change `b` to `char*`. Of course if you don't copy then when you change `a` you'll also change `b`. BTW I'd suggest to use `strcpy` for strings (mostly, but not only, for clarity)

Comment: Yes you can just use pointer arithmetics. But you can't delimit the end of the string, since it's implied by a ending character, the NUL byte.

Comment: What is the relation between the `memcpy()`example and the `printf()` example? Also the `printf()` example won't compile.

Comment: You should use `strlen(a)`, not `strlen(a)-1`, otherwise you are leaving the destination string without a null character. Alternatively, you can simply call `strcpy(b,a)`.

Comment: @barakmanos: Even using `strlen(a)` does **not** add the 0-terminator.

Comment: @alk: Yep, should be `strlen(a)+1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fwrite from stdio.h you can print any part of your C-style string as you please as fwrite takes a pointer to any character in the string and expects you to supply a size instead of using a null-byte termination.

The declaration of fwrite is as follows:

`size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );`

See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/

So you can write

```
const char* a = "foobarfoobar";
fwrite(a + 3, 6, 1, stdout);
```

which will print the substring "barfoo" to stdout.

There are also several other functions in the standard library that take a pointer and a size for raw memory management that can be used if you want to handle substrings without having to copy the original string just to insert a null-byte at the end of the substring.
Like fwrite these functions allow you to handle any arbitrary binary data but are therefore also suitable for character string manipulation and handling.

As you edited your question, here's a more general explanation for passing around parts of an array:

Functions that accept arrays containing arbitrary data always take two parameters. One pointer to the array and one for the size of the array. Of course they can also take additional arguments, but these two are the minimum.

```
void some_function(const void *ptr, size_t size);
```

if you have an array `const char[] foo = "some data"` you can use pointer arithmetic to determine the start of a sub part. `foo+n` will generate a pointer to the n+1th element of the array. You can therefore pass `foo + 2` as `ptr` to `some_function` making `ptr` point to the 3rd element of the foo array. In this case this is the memory address that contains the letter 'm' of the string "some data". Starting from that position you can tell the function the size of the array through the `size` argument. If you choose size to be 5 you can call `some_function` as `some_function(foo + 2, 5);` which will make `some_function` effectively see "me da".

To compare two subarrays you can use the function `memcmp` from string.h (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/).
This function also accepts just like `some_function` a pointer and a size argument. Additionally it accepts a second pointer to the memory location to compare to.

```
const char[] foo = "some data";
const char[] bar = "same database";

memcmp(foo + 2, bar + 2, 7); // Will return 0 indicating equality as foo+2 -> foo+2+7 and bar+2 -> bar+2+7 both result in the substring "me data".
```

Comment: What are those please ? My point is not only printing but reusing for sending messages by sockets as well, passing subarray to function...

Comment: Do you program on Linux? If so, you can use the write system call to write to sockets (http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) which also accepts a pointer and a size argument. But I don't know about Windows or any specific frameworks, if you plan to use them. And passing arrays in general is simple.

Comment: As arrays are implicitly casted to a pointer of the array type, all functions accepting an array also expect you to tell them the size. you can therefore use any offset as start of the new array and provide any size to slice the original array. Functions that accept C-style strings are special, because they rely on the terminating null-byte. But there's often an equivalent function that takes arbitrary data where a size parameter is required.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the length of your %s in the printf to only display the part you are interested in:

`printf("my array is %.2s\n", a);`

Comment: printf was an example, I would like to use this array anywhere in my code and being able to reference a subpart of it. Let me improve my question. I added a point for you though ;)

Comment: I think your question needs more context. If you want to pass slices of the original string to other points of your program, then a pointer to the start and a size of the slice is probably easier to use.Be aware however that if you do not copy, any change to the slice will impact the original string.

Comment: Thanks how to reference the whole string then ? Say, in the function ? How could I compare one subarray and another array ? if(*subarray+1..*subarray+4 == array) ? a loop ? nothing more elegant ? Isn't it slower than copying in the first place ?

Comment: Comparing strings *is* done with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You may encapsulate your original string to some struct which carries the reference and length:

```
typedef struct
{
    const char* ptr;
    size_t len;
} my_str_t;

char a[] = "hello";

my_str_t b = { a, 2 }; 
my_str_t c = { a+2, 3 }; 

send( sock, b.ptr, b.len, 0 );   // sends "he"
send( sock, c.ptr, c.len, 0 );   // sends "llo"

printf( "%.*s\n", b.len, b.ptr );    // prints "he"
```